# Spring AmqpTemplate nested autowiring

Tags: java, spring, junit, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a service that is responsible for placing a message on a RabbitMQ queue. I have set up the AMQP config in such a way that I can autowire the  AmqpTemplate class into the service. This config works when I move the logic into the body of a JUnit test.

However, When I create a test with the service autowired in and call the method to trigger the AmqpTemplates convertAndSend method nothing happens. Using wireshark I have seen that it still handshakes with the RabbitMQ server but no exchange is created and no messages appear in any queue even when I am making use of RabbitMQ's firehose trace options.

The code is as follows:

```
<!-- AMQP messaging configurations starts here -->
<!-- Spring AMQP connection factory -->
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
                           host="localhost"
                           port="5672"
                           username="guest"
                           password="guest"
                           channel-cache-size="25"/>

<!-- Queues -->
<rabbit:queue name="test.queue"/>

<!-- Exchanges with their queue bindings -->
<rabbit:topic-exchange name="test.exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="test.queue" pattern="test.*"/>
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>

<!-- Spring AMQP template - Creates a bean which can send a message to the topicExchange-->
<rabbit:template id="testTemplate"
                 connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                 exchange="test.exchange"/>

<!-- Spring AMQP Admin -->
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory"/>
```

The above code segment appears in my application context that is used for the JUnit tests.

```
@Service
public class AsyncQueueServiceImplementation implements AsyncQueueService
{

  @Autowired
  private AmqpTemplate template;

  @Override
  @Async
  public void publish()
  {
    template.convertAndSend("test.debug", "test payload");
  }
}
```

The above code segment is the service that is responsible for actually sending an object to the AmqpTemplate. Please not that the AmqpTemplate is autowired in here.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:application-context-unitTests.xml" })
public class AsyncTraceServiceImplementationTest
{

  @Autowired
  AsyncTraceService traceService;

  @Test
  public void testPublishAtDebugLevel()
  {
    traceService.publish();
  }
}
```

The above segment is the JUnit test. It uses the application context that contains all the rabbit mq configuration. It then autowires in the service and calls the message.

When I place simple System.out.println's around, I can see that in both the service the AmqpTemplate is instantiated but doesn't seem to do what is expected.

Could this perhaps be an issue with the context not being passed on to the service for some reason.

I have tried using ReflectionTestUtils to set the template field in the service from the Junit test however I was unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue.

The issue was in the RabbitMQ topics that I was using. The exchange received an unknown topic and as a result did nothing with it.

Correcting this resulted in the messages appearing in the correct queue as the exchange was then able to route the messages correctly.